# xbox 360 controller problems

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Use Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming Controller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14849/how-to-use-xbox-360-wireless-gaming-controller)

Hello everyone another new Linux user here.Most things are going well except for the 360 controller.There are so many posts about this it gets a little confusing on which to follow.Anyways someone told me that ubuntu 12.04 comes with a 360 wireless receiver and its just plug and play.When i plug my receiver in and run jstest-gtk 4 generic xbox pad come up in the joystick preferences window.now the controller itself isnt even on,and when it is on it doesnt sync.All four lights just flash.What am I doing incorrectly? Before it is asked yes this controller & receiver both work in Windows 7

Comment: I notice this it's actually sync but it cant activate the controller leds.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct.Im not sure why 4 generic xbox controllers are showing up,but good enough :)